# How to enable cloudbuild.yaml for zip-based CloudFunction deployments?

Tags: python, git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

Given some generic Python code, structured like ...

```
cloudbuild.yaml
requirements.txt
functions/
    folder_a/
        test/
            main_test.py
        main.py
```

If I'm ...

- creating a .zip from above folder and
- using either Terraform's [`google_cloudfunctions_function`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/cloudfunctions_function.html) resource or [`gcloud functions deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/repo) to upload/deploy the function

... it seems the build configuration for cloudbuild (`cloudbuild.yaml`) included in the .zip is never considered during build (i.e. while / prior to resolving `requirements.txt`).

I've set up `cloudbuild.yaml` to grant access to a private github repository (which contains a dependency listed in `requirements.txt`). Unfortunately, build fails with (terraform output):

> Error: Error waiting for Updating CloudFunctions Function: Error code 3, message: Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "`pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:\nCommand \"git clone -q ssh://git@github.com/SomeWhere/SomeThing.git /tmp/pip-req-build-a29nsum1\" failed with error code 128 in None\n\nerror: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": "92DCE9EA"}}

According to [cloud build docs](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/access-private-github-repos#configure_the_build), a `cloudbuild.yaml` can be specified using `gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml .` -- is there any way to supply that parameter to `gcloud functions deploy` (or even Terraform), too? I'd like to stay with the current, "transparent" code build, i.e. I do not want to set up code build separately but just upload my zip and have the code be built and deployed "automatically", while respecting `codebuild.yaml`.

Comment: Can you share you `terraform` and `cloudbuild.yaml` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to authenticate to a private Git repo via SSH. [This is unfortunately not currently supported by Cloud Functions.](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#using_private_dependencies)

The alternative would be to vendor your private dependency into the directory before creating your `.zip` file.